# How to make android phone a wireless printer server?

Tags: android, server, printing

Is there any software with which I can make my usb printer a wireless printer with my old android phone as a printer server? Can anybody please explain? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you leaving the phone next to the printer?

Comment: @RohitGupta I have an old Android phone, I want to use it as a printer server to make my usb printer a wireless printer. How can I do it?

Comment: It would be better if you edited the question to add more details.  I still don't have an answer.  Are you going to carry on using the phone per normal, so it is mobile ?  Or is it going to stay next to the printer, perhaps even wired to it permanently?

Comment: @RohitGupta I casked the later question. I have an old Android phone which I don't use for phone purpose. I want to make it a permanent printer server for my usb printer. How can I do that?

Comment: The good news is samba includes a linux based file and print server and android is linux based.  From there is bad news.  You would have to learn how to write an android app which includes a samba implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am the author.

Yes, https://netprinter.app only allowed printing from your phone to printers somewhere else on your local network earlier but recently it was enhanced to provide just the functionality you mention: run in a server mode to accept incoming requests sent to a directly attached printer.

Comment: This is impressive!